# hide y axis label on mouse hover in nvd3 bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot, nvd3.js

I am trying to disable the y value from being shown when the mouse hovers over a circle in nvd3 Bubble/Scatter chart. The live code is [here](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav). I tried this

```
var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
            .showDistY(false)
```

but it only makes the line to the y axis disappear and not the y axis value. How do I disable the y axis label from being shown when the mouse hovers over the circles/bubbles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the y tooltip content to `null` to achieve this:

```
var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
        .showDistY(false)
        .tooltipYContent(null);
```

Comment: Can you help me with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689858/create-invisible-bubble-in-nvd3-scatter-chart