# create invisible bubble in nvd3 scatter chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to create some bubbles on the scatter chart which are invisible. I do not want the tooltip also to show up for these bubbles. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Not with just NVD3, but you could add them afterwards using D3.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff How can I do so with D3 to the same bubble chart?

Comment: You add the circle elements using the scales from the NVD3 chart.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I did not understand. Could you help with some sample code.

Comment: E.g. `d3.select(".nv-point-paths").append("circle").attr("r", 10).attr("cx", 100).attr("cy", 100);`.